# multiple complex calculated ng-classes

Tags: angularjs

I have this td with a complex ng-class that works just fine.

`<td ng-repeat="column in columns" 
   ng-class="'cell-value-' + column.name + '-'+ row[column.name] | safeClassName" 
   >`

I want to add another class to the td that is just the column name. This doesn't seem to work

`<td ng-repeat="column in columns" 
   ng-class="'cell-value-' + column.name + '-'+ row[column.name] | safeClassName" 
   ng-class="'cell-column-' + column.name | safeClassName"
   >`

For a little side info, safeClassName converts spaces to dashes and filters out invalid characters

How can I a second computed class to my td?

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS does not support multiple ngClass directives on the same element, but it does support an expression that evaluates to string with class names space-delimited, or an array of class names.

Since the logic is becoming complex, I would move the logic to generate the class name into a view model (or $scope) function.

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-class="vm.computeClass(column)" />
```

The controller should have a function then something like the following:

```
vm.computeClass = function(column) {
  var classNames = [];

  classNames.push('cell-value-' + column.name + '-'+ row[column.name] | safeClassName);
  classNames.push('cell-column-' + column.name | safeClassName);

  return classNames;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array syntax for ng-class

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" 
   ng-class="['cell-value-' + column.name + '-'+ row[column.name] | safeClassName,'cell-column-' + column.name | safeClassName]"
 >
```